# React API Fetch resolve promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, promise

I have a functional component Users.js and a seperate Api.js.
Below the code which gives me the error:

```
// Function Users.js
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(fetchUsers());
        const data = fetchUsers();
        setUsers(data);
        //setUsers(fetchUsers());
}, []);

// Api.js
export const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    return await data.json();
};
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: users.map is not a function
```

This is because I return a promise, which I could see by evaluating the console.log(fetchUsers()).
How can I fix this issue, because it worked as long as I used the function fetchUsers inside my function and not in a seperate file...

Comment: Call `.then()` on the returned Promise to obtain the `data` it resolves to, and then set the state: `fetchUsers().then(data => setUsers(data))` (alternatively, create an async function inside your useEffect(), which await's the promise). You can also just return `data.json()`, there is no need to await it, as the value returned by await will get wrapped back into a Promise again once you return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to update your code to give you two examples:

```
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const data = await fetchUsers();
      setUsers(data);
    }

    getData()
    
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox </h1>
      {
        (users || []).map(item => <span>{item.name}</span>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export const fetchUsers = async () => {
  const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  return await data.json();
};
```

The second one is better than the first one, I used .then() on your function:

```
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {

    fetchUsers().then(items => setUsers(items))
    
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox </h1>
      {
        (users || []).map(item => <span>{item.name}</span>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

In both cases I am able to retrieve the users.
I tried it in a single file but you can of course move the functions where you prefer.

I suggest you, before to render data, to check if the users array exists (`users || []`) or to give it a default empty array value `[users, setUsers] = useState([])`

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the promise which is returned and then set the state.

```js
fetchUsers().then((result) => setUsers(result));
```